# What are the diferences between installing NetBeans with JDK and just the Java Platform?

Tags: java, java-8, javac, netbeans-8

I've been programming in java for a couple of months(only desktop applications), and recently I've decided to learn a little bit of Android development. To develop something for Android devices I know that is necessary to have the JDK installed.

I installed JDK with Netbeans, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html, few months ago, and everything seamed to be fine. I did some java desktop applications and they worked well, so I thought that the JDK was installed on my computer.

I saw online that to check if JDK is installed it's just check the version of javac, but when typed 'javac -version' on cmd, it did not recognize as a command. Wasn't suppose to recognize? Technically I have already installed along with Netbeans.

I appreciate if someone could explain me

Thank you

Comment: First, this particular error can be solved by doing a quick search with your favorite search engine.  That being said, you can fix this by adding the JDK installation to your environment path.  The method will vary based on your OS.  Homework: Figure out how to do the above.

Comment: Thank you, and I am sorry for the lack of knowledge

Comment: It's all good Hugo, we all have to start somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

"javac -version" will only work in the bin folder of java, where it resides, not as a OS command. That's why for example you have to add an environment variable on Windows to let the system know where it has to find the javac.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin>javac -version

javac 1.8.0_92

Comment: Ow , I see! 
In case I had only installed the JVM, would I still have the java folder but no javac ? Thanks, man